# Calculation with rounded values in Excel

Tags: excel

I experienced some weird calculation using value from other columns after using `ROUND()` and `ROUNDDOWN()`. The end result of calculation between these 2 values wasn't expected.

I've ported over the issue I've faced to Google Docs and the end result is similar. You can see the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-nXRbaLbSUc0X6ZyUZAUGCGBzeiXdTKLjDf-o4HJOOQ/edit?usp=sharing).

First I simply give a float value, then I `ROUND()` it, then I `ROUNDDOWN()` the `ROUND()` value. Finally, I will take `ROUNDDOWN()` value and minus it with the `ROUND()` value.

The end result included quite many decimal places and the value wasn't even close to the initial value I specified which is really weird. See the spreadsheet linked above to get a better idea.

The expected result should be 0.04 or -0.04. Not with a bunch of 9s.

Comment: This is expected behaviour, and is due the limited precission that can be stored in a floating point variable.  See my answer to proposed duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the values in column D aren't rounded.

When you round a floating-point value, the result is still floating point.  The rounding changes the way it's represented, but it's still a mantissa and an exponent, which when combined correctly, give you a number fairly close to what you want.  But not *exactly* what you want (usually).

If you were to round the values in column D after the subtraction, you'd get what you are expecting.